# Runtime error 1004 : Unable to get the PivotTables property of the Worksheet class

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Excel VBA and I am trying to create a pivot table using only Row Field with the following codes but encountered error 1004 and would need help de-bugging.

I've indicated the error occurrence on the codes right after the comments 
//
'Macros above create a pivot cache and address to insert the new pivot table
// 
for easy referencing.

Appreciate any help on this.

```vb
Sub getpivotUI2()    
    '**strong text**    
    ' getpivotUI2 Macro    
    ' Create PivotTable from Task_Sheet to filter duplicate bill (UI2)    
    '

    Dim P2Sheet, TSheet As Worksheet    
    Dim P2Cache As PivotCache    
    Dim P2Table As PivotTable    
    Dim P2Range As Range    
    Dim L2Row, L2Col As Long   

    ' Declaring the variables above

    Set TSheet = Worksheets("Task_Sheet")    
    Set P2Sheet = Worksheets("pivot_UI2")   

    L2Row = TSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row    
    L2Col = TSheet.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set P2Range = TSheet.Cells(4, 1).Resize(L2Row, L2Col)

    'Macros above determine where the cursor is referenced

    P2Sheet.Cells.Delete 'Removing all previous data the pivotTable worksheet
    Set P2Cache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _    
      (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=P2Range)

    Set P2Table = P2Cache.CreatePivotTable _    
      (TableDestination:=P2Sheet.Cells(3, 1), TableName:="PivotTableUI2")

    'Macros above create a pivot cache and address to insert the new pivot table     

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableUI2").PivotFields("UI2") '**<-- ERROR OCCURANCE**   
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With           

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableUI2").PivotTables("PivotTableUI2").PivotFields("Count_UI2")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Function = xlCount
        .Name = "Count of UI2"
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableUI2").PivotTables("PivotTableUI2").PivotFields("R Patient" & Chr(10) & "Count")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Function = xlCount
        .Name = "Count of R Patient"
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableUI2").PivotTables("PivotTableUI2").PivotFields("PR Patient" & Chr(10) & "Count")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Function = xlCount
        .Name = "Count of PR Patient"
    End With

    'Macros above inserts a row field and data field in the pivot table
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use the `{}` button on the editor to format code, instead double `newline`.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:python-3.x]?

Comment: Error on tagging python-3 , my apologies.

Comment: @JonL read my answer and code below, let me know if this helped you solve your error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below, explanation inside the code's comments

```
Option Explicit

Sub getpivotUI2()

    ' getpivotUI2 Macro
    ' Create PivotTable from Task_Sheet to filter duplicate bill (UI2)

    Dim P2Sheet As Worksheet, TSheet As Worksheet
    Dim P2Cache As PivotCache
    Dim P2Table As PivotTable
    Dim P2Range As Range
    Dim L2Row As Long, L2Col As Long

    ' Declaring the variables above

    Set TSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Task_Sheet")
    Set P2Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("pivot_UI2")

    With TSheet
        L2Row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        L2Col = .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        Set P2Range = .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(L2Row, L2Col)) ' set the data source of the Pivot-Cache
    End With

    'Macros above determine where the cursor is referenced

    P2Sheet.Cells.Delete 'Removing all previous data the pivotTable worksheet

    ' set the Pivot-Cache object
    Set P2Cache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(xlDatabase, P2Range.Address(0, 0, xlA1, xlExternal))

    ' set the Pivot-Table object
    Set P2Table = P2Sheet.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=P2Cache, TableDestination:=P2Sheet.Range("A3"), TableName:="PivotTableUI2")

    'Macros above create a pivot cache and address to insert the new pivot table

    ' ~~~ For Debug Only ~~~
    Dim PTFld As PivotField

    For Each PTFld In P2Table.PivotFields
        Debug.Print PTFld.Name
    Next PTFld

    With P2Table.PivotFields("UI2")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    ' rest of your Pivot-Fields code …

End Sub
```

---

I've added a section in the `Sub` above that makes sure your Pivot-Table has a field "*U12*".

When you run this part:

```
' ~~~ For Debug Only ~~~
Dim PTFld As PivotField

For Each PTFld In P2Table.PivotFields
    Debug.Print PTFld.Name
Next PTFld
```

You should get the following value in the immediate window:

[image]

Comment: Codes worked, thank you. For my education, what does "Address(0, 0, xlA1, xlExternal))" meant in Set P2Cache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(xlDatabase, P2Range.Address(0, 0, xlA1, xlExternal))?